# How to install modman-php on windows?

Tags: php, wamp, modman

A GitHub user developed something but did not provide any installation instructions. I hope someone can help me to install [modman-php](https://github.com/sitewards/modman-php).

It comes with three files:

modman.bat
modman.php
modman.sh

**Usage example:**

```
php modman.php init
```

Where do I have to move the file `modman.php` in order to make it work?

I put it in `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.35` but if I execute `php modman.php init` then I get "*Could not open input file: modman.php*".

Comment: If I were you, I would create an issue on that repository, asking the developer to give some installation instructions.

Comment: just put all the files in the same folder and run modman.bat

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, There is already an issue about this which is from 2015 and still not answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. You have to put the files `modman.bat` and `modman.php` in any folder and then puth the path to the file "modman.bat" in your system path variable.

Then you can use modman from CMD and PowerShell.